# Saving the recurring events in database if they are edited

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, recurring-events, ice-cube

I am making a calender app where someone could edit a task.

I have a task which has got task name, description and due_date. This task has to be repeated on a quarterly basis. If someone goes to the task of the next quarter and clicks on the task, I want an object to be created at that point of time with due_date of this task so that other operations like editing can be done on it.

I am able to show the tasks on calendar but don't know how to start with saving the object thing.

Since I am using [ice_cube](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube) to make recurring event I thought I could do it with persistence as per the wiki. However I seem to be stuck and don't know how to move forward.

It will be great if someone can point me on how to make this use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which is working for me is following :-

1) Identify that the event is recurring and not the one which is saved in the database (IceCube will help in this)

2) When click on the event which is recurring pass a parameter with the link (say recurring event)

3) Check in the controller if the parameter is recurring event then create a task in the backend and redirect to the show of that task (while creating the task fill the details of the task in the backend)

Hope this helps